# スクロールできるときのhtml要素の高さがブラウザの画面の高さと同じにならないのでなぜですか？

Tags: html, css

html要素よりも大きなボディがあるとhtml要素にはスクロールバーが作られますが、なぜhtml要素の高さはスクロールバーがあるにもかかわらずbodyと同じ高さになるのでしょうか？

画面の高さをスマホ想定で586にしましたがhtmlはbodyと同じ1700になってしまいます。本物のスマホのブラウザーだと違う結果になりますか？
画像のウィンドウのhtml要素の高さはブラウザの画面の高さと同じ高さになると思っていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<html><body><style>body{margin:0}</style>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 画像のウィンドウのhtml要素の高さはブラウザの画面の高さと同じ高さになる

その認識がそもそも誤解だということです。html 要素は、論理的な html 文書のことであって、ブラウザの画面とは何の関係もありません。

[html 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)は、head 要素と body 要素を各 1 個ずつ含むもので、[head 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)は文書のメタデータを定義するブロックで、

> メモ: `<head>` は主に人間が読むためのものではなく、機械処理のための情報を保持するためのものです。

とあるように、ブラウザを通じて人間が見ているウィンドウの視覚的な状態に直接関係するコンテンツ情報（[body 要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)内に記述するもの）に加えて、そうではない情報（非コンテンツ）を保持し、この body と head を合わせたものが全体として論理的に html になっているわけです。

つまり、html 要素は、ウィンドウサイズという、ユーザーに表示される情報に直接関係があるものではないということです（結果的に、body を内包しているので、devtool 等によって body と同サイズの扱いになるだけです）。

Comment: ブラウザの画面とは何の関係もないならとすると、devtoolのウィンドウのhtml要素にoverflowを追加すると、どうしてスクロールバーが消えたり現れたりするでしょうか？

Comment: @Uarcin 継承されているだけではないでしょうか？　試しに、html ではなく body 要素の style に overflow を指定してみた場合と違いはありますか？

Comment: ありがとうございました。おっしゃるとおりでした。